# Difficulty Accessing Visible Property Using System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive by reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, system.io.compression

The Library loads and I am able to view the ziparchiveentries in the debugger but I can not access the methods or properties of the ziparchiveentry object array by reflection:

```
Assembly CompressionLib = Assembly.LoadWithPartialName("System.IO.Compression");
Module CompressionModule = CompressionLib.GetModule("System.IO.Compression.dll");
Type ZipArchiveType = CompressionModule.GetType("System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive");
Type ZipArchiveEntryType = CompressionModule.GetType("System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry");
ConstructorInfo UnzipConstructor = ZipArchiveType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(System.IO.Stream) });
object UnzipInstance = UnzipConstructor.Invoke(new object[] Plugin.PluginFiles[0].fileData });
MethodInfo UnzipGetEntries = ZipArchiveType.GetMethod("get_Entries");
ICollection UnzippableFilesCollection = (ICollection)UnzipGetEntries.Invoke(UnzipInstance, null);
object[] UnzippableFiles = new ArrayList(UnzippableFilesCollection).ToArray();
```

At this point I can view in the debugger that for example:

```
UnzippableFiles[25]
{pt-br/ACResources.resources.dll}
    Archive: {System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive}
    CompressedLength: 78659
    ExternalAttributes: -2119958528
    FullName: "pt-br/ACResources.resources.dll"
    LastWriteTime: {1/8/2019 7:29:04 AM -08:00}
    Length: 232696
    Name: "ACResources.resources.dll"
```

However example:

```
ZipArchiveEntryType.GetType().GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(UnzippableFiles[25])
```

returns with an error:

```
    `'ZipArchiveEntryType.GetType().GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(UnzippableFiles[25])' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetException'`
Message: "Object does not match target type."
```

Comment: What if you do `UnzippableFiles[25].GetType()` in the `Watch` or `Immediate window`, what does it output?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it by removing the GetType() which is unresolved in context:

```
ZipArchiveEntryType.GetProperty("FullName").GetValue(new ArrayList((ICollection)ZipArchiveType.GetProperty("Entries").GetValue(UnzipInstance)).ToArray()[11])
```